# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, foreach

Hello Guys this is my code in controller. And This foreach loop is for adding new lines. So when I do not add new line I'm getting the error called **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** I know that error is occurring because the row is sending null value, but I don't know the solution for this. Please help me out with this. Thanks al ot. Every help and comment is appreciated. :)

```
 $total_add_more = 0;

        foreach($add_more_line as $each_key => $each_val ) {

            if($add_more_year_button[$each_key] == 'month'){

                $total_add_more += $each_val; 
            }else {
                $total_add_more += $each_val * 12;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I assume that it is 'empty' sometimes? You could 'cast' it as an array i.e.: _`foreach((array) $add_more_line as ...`_ which will keep the 'foreach loop 'happy'.

Answer (score 1):

Always `$add_more_line` should be an array to execute `foreach`. Do one of following things to prevent this error.

1. Check the variable with [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and if so you can execute `foreach`
2. As [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) said cast it inside the `froeach`.
3. Initialize the array in Controller before assign values.

Code :

```
if(is_array($add_more_line)){
    // Do the job
}
```

or

```
foreach((array)$add_more_line as $each_key => $each_val){
   // Code 
}
```

or

```
 $add_more_line = array();
```

Comment: Hello @Eranda :) this worked finely and is best way. Thanks alot

Comment: Checking with `is_array` works sometimes, but not always. You can pass objects that implement [Traversable Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) to a foreach, not only arrays...

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter :) . I didn't know about Traversable Interface.

Comment: @Eranda You're welcome. By the way, that's what makes it possible to iterate over a Laravel collection with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check if the `$add_more_line` variable before doing the foreach?

```
if ($add_more_line)
{
    // your code
}
```